# Number of elements of $\{1,-1,1,-1,\ldots,1\}$ and $\{1,-1,1,-1,\ldots\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> How many elements each set has?
>
> (a) $\{1,-1,1,-1,\ldots,1\}$
>
> (b) $\{1,-1,1,-1,\ldots \}$

It is a problem from a book that has two parts and I typed them here respectively.

For part $(a)$ we have $1$ and $-1$ alternatively, hence it has two elements $1,-1$. But I'm not sure about part $(b)$. Does it have two elements too?

Comment: It seems (a) could have only 1 element, since it might stop at the initial 1 in the dotted list. But (b) definitely goes on forever, so has 2 elements.

Comment: Usually the elements of the set are not repeated (unless we are talking about multisets), so in the second case also you have only two elements.

Answer (score 1):

The "..." mean that the pattern is being repeated hence b has two elements since the number of times an element is repeated does not matter